# Xquery html formatting

Tags: xquery

I'm new to Xquery. I have a requirement of rewriting the API response into custom xml format.

**Input file format:**

```
 <root>    <_1>
   <dataType>
      <name>XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg])</name>
      <term>M185</term>
      <type>XVar</type>
   </dataType>
   <values>305</values>
   <values>335</values>   </_1>    <_2>
   <dataType>
      <name>XVar(DO (2) [%])</name>
      <term>M199</term>
      <type>XVar</type>
   </dataType>
   <values>12</values>
   <values>33</values>
      </_2>    <_3>
   <dataType>
      <name>Maturity</name>
      <type>Maturity</type>
   </dataType>
   <values>0</values>
   <values>0.73600054</values>
       </_3> </root>
```

**Expected output:**

```
 <element> <XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg]> 305</XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg]>
 <XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg]> 335</XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg]> <XVar(DO (2)[%])>
 12</XVar(DO (2) [%])> <XVar(DO (2) [%])>33 </XVar(DO (2) [%])>
 <Maturity>0</Maturity> <Maturity>0.73600054</Maturity> </element>
```

no of nodes (dataType -> name) will vary in each input file and also
 Values will be dynamics .

currently using the below code.

```
let $input:= /root for $i in $input//values 
return <element>
 <name>{$i/../dataType/name/text()}</name> <values>{$i/text()} </values>
 </element>
```

but all data are coming in  and  . my requirement is to
 keep the node name as  {$i/../dataType/name/text()} as values should
 be {$i/text()} -

for the input file sample ideally there should be three different
 nodes and its values.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: The "expected output" is invalid XML. `<element>` and `<Maturity>` are fine, but the elements beginning with `<xVar` are not valid element names. Can you please revise this or clarify?

Comment: Hi Joewiz, Thank u for responding.

Comment: Hi Joewiz, Thank u for responding.  Actually value of <name>XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg])</name> from input file should be used to in output structure .  if required we can take       <term>M185</term>.  Requirement is restructure the xml to generate so that end result can be generated in csv.
XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg] , XVar(DO (2) [%]),Maturity
------------------------------------------------------
305,   12,  0
335,   33,  0.73600054

Comment: If the ultimate requirement is to output CSV, you can simply use string-join() to join each cell in a row with comma, and again to join each row with a linebreak (`&#10;`). Is that an acceptable approach, or do you need this intermediate XML format of the data?

Comment: Hi Joewiz,  Can you give me some sample code using string-join().  Query will be using in informatica cloud and results will be stored in csv file . out file will be as follows XVar(Osmo [mOsmol/kg]) XVar(DO (2) [%]) Maturity
305 NaN 0
305 NaN 0.73600054
302 NaN 1.7750001
298 NaN 2.70599985
312 NaN 3.69799995
NaN NaN 3.94799995
310 NaN 4.71299982
325 NaN 5.86399984